# Getting error while counting the relational data in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting an error while counting the 'with' data in laravel Eloquent Query.
What output I need is to count the number of data related to **promotiondetails** and use the where condition if it is greater than 0.

```
$category = $request->input('category');

$sqlDistance = DB::raw('(6371 * acos(cos(radians('.$request->latitude.')) 
    * cos(radians(latitude)) 
    * cos(radians(longitude) 
    - radians('.$request->longitude.') ) 
    + sin(radians('.$request->latitude.') ) 
    * sin(radians(latitude))))');

$offers = Promotion::with(['promotiondetails' => function($q) use($category) {
    $q->where('premium', '=', 0);
    if($category != 'all'){
        $q->where('category', '=', $category);
    }
    $q->whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(expiry_date, "%d/%m/%Y") >= CURDATE()');
    $q->where('status', '=', 1);
}])
->select('*')
->addSelect(DB::raw("round({$sqlDistance}, 2) AS distance"))
->having("distance", "<", $request->radius)
->where('type', 2)
->where('status', 1)
->where(function ($query){
    $query->where('count(promotiondetails)', '>', 0);
    
})
->orderBy('distance')
->paginate(($request->input('page') == 'all' ? 0 : 10));
```

Can Someone help me on this?

**Error:**

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count(promotiondetails)' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Please always post also any ERRORs so that we can help you better.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Please check

Comment: I would think that you need to use HAVING instead of where because count is an aggregate function https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-count-in-a-where-clause

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig After using having in place of where its showing output but empty promotiondetails. What I have asked is if promotiondetails is empty not to show Promotion Data also. That means it will skip if promotiondetails data will not be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Has** or **whereHas** function to query about a relation's existence. You can find more details here in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

```
$category = $request->input('category');

$sqlDistance = DB::raw('(6371 * acos(cos(radians('.$request->latitude.')) 
    * cos(radians(latitude)) 
    * cos(radians(longitude) 
    - radians('.$request->longitude.') ) 
    + sin(radians('.$request->latitude.') ) 
    * sin(radians(latitude))))');

$offers = Promotion::with(['promotiondetails' => function($q) use($category) {
    $q->where('premium', '=', 0);
    if($category != 'all'){
        $q->where('category', '=', $category);
    }
    $q->whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(expiry_date, "%d/%m/%Y") >= CURDATE()');
    $q->where('status', '=', 1);
}])
->select('*')
->addSelect(DB::raw("round({$sqlDistance}, 2) AS distance"))
->having("distance", "<", $request->radius)
->where('type', 2)
->where('status', 1)
->has('promotiondetails')
->orderBy('distance')
->paginate(($request->input('page') == 'all' ? 0 : 10));
```

Comment: Its not working with where and whereHas. I think because the query for promotiondetails is not affecting the whole query. I also checked with withCount it is returning 2 where their are empty data in promotiondetails in output.

Comment: Then you may check your relation.

Comment: This is only the relation.